# Swagger UI with swagger.yaml in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

We have a SpringBoot (version 1.5.12) REST Api with springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui (version 2.9.2)

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   @Bean
   public Docket swagger() {
       return new Docket(SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
```

I can see the Swagger UI at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

How can I configure swagger-ui to read my swagger.yaml/json configuration file instead to generate it automatically? 
I tried several configuration without success.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a class which can provide a `SwaggerResourcesProvider` `@Primary` bean, which specifies the location of the config as below (considering the `swagger.json` file is present in `src/main/resources`)

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerSpecConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
        return () -> {
            SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
            wsResource.setName("new spec");
            wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
            wsResource.setLocation("/swagger.json");

            List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>(defaultResourcesProvider.get());
            resources.add(wsResource);
            return resources;
        };
    }
}
```

Then on the Swagger UI, you'll be able to select the spec from your json (named as `new spec` here) as below:

[image]

Here's a link to the Springfox documentation:
http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#aggregating-multiple-swagger-specifications-in-the-same-swagger-ui

Comment: swagger.json should be in src/main/resources/static

Comment: A small note, I tried this with a yaml from http://editor.swagger.io/, but it only worked once I used the editor's feature to convert to json.

Comment: I have used `springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0` , yaml and json both works fine all the times!

Comment: If you put a `resources.clear()` before adding your resource, it will be the only one shown in ui.